# Rselenium unable to get page source - fromJSON error

Tags: json, r, selenium, rselenium

I am trying to use the RSelenium package, and I have noticed that the getPageSource() method fails on certain websites (but not on others) - see this example, using websites that appear in the Relenium docs:

```
library(RSelenium)
remDr = remoteDriver$new()
startServer()
remDr$open()
```

## this fails:

```
remDr$navigate("http://www.google.com")
left(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]],300)
```

> Error in fromJSON(content, handler, default.size, depth,
>   allowComments,  :    invalid JSON input

## this succeeds:

```
remDr$navigate("http://www.bbc.co.uk")
left(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]],300)
```

> [1] "\r\nhttp://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"
>   lang=\"en\" class=\"orb-js bbcdotcom bbcdotcom-responsive ads-enabled
>   js flexbox flexboxlegacy csscolumns cssgradients csstransforms
>   fontface generatedcontent svg inlinesvg cssfilters bbcdotcom-init
>   bbccom-group-4 bbcdotcom-analytics-init wwhp"

Does anyone know a solution or workaround to get the pagesource?  Note that the example using the google site as described in the dos does work - RSelenium can find and access elements in the page.  It is just the getPageSource() method that fails.